# NixOS: No space left on /nix/store during nixos-rebuild or nixops deploy

Tags: package-management, disk-usage, nixos

When doing upgrades (especially large ones) on NixOS with a relatively small root partition, I sometimes run out of space after a bunch of new packages are installed in `/nix/store`. Eg:

```
error: preallocating file of 716320 bytes: No space left on device
```

My usual approach has been to run

```
nix-collect-garbage
```

or even

```
nix-collect-garbage -d
```

which frees up space by deleting not only the old generations *but also the new packages I'm installing*.

The next download attempt will download the new packages all over again, and -- if enough space was freed -- may succeed.

Is there a way to **delete only the older derivations**?

Comment: How about cleaning **before** starting the update?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Deleting old generations (particularly the last one booted from) is a little risky, and of course still doesn't guarantee that enough space will be freed to avoid downloading repeatedly. Sometimes you have to GC, do a partial update, GC again, and then finally finish the update. It can be pretty annoying without a way to tell whether enough space is available.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 possible solutions here. Firstly rather than delete all old generations you can instead specify those for deletion. See the manual [entry](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-env) for the `nix-env --delete-generations` operation. Secondly the `nix-store --optimise` operation [(ref)](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sec-nix-store) may be useful for you also.